# IOS UICollectionView Register nib for UICollectionViewCell not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

here's my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   ...
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(160, 160)];
    [layout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:5.f];
    [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

    _photoPicker = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10 , self.view.frame.size.width - 20, 160 ) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_photoPicker registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"photoUploadCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@" photoUploadCell"];

    //[_photoPicker registerClass:[photoUploadCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoUploadCell"];
    _photoPicker.backgroundColor = gray;
    _photoPicker.delegate = self;
    _photoPicker.dataSource = self;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:_photoPicker];

}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    photoUploadCollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoUploadCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

This code crash at `photoUploadCollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];` and I get this error :

> 2015-05-26 10:45:29.363 Free Sale[4505:55482] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UICollectionView.m:3454
>   2015-05-26 10:45:29.374 Free Sale[4505:55482] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with
>   identifier photoCell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Any one know this wired issue ?

Comment: Check the reuse-identifier and nib name is spelt correctly?

Comment: I've checked that many times.

Comment: And _photoPicker is definitely not nil, right?

Comment: `photoCell` is not registered.. 

is this the actual code you have? because you have a white space `forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`..

Comment: remove the space before cell identifier.

Comment: @0yeoj You just saved my day I was stucked here for  about 2 hours thank's a lot Post your comment in answer

Comment: You are welcome, always and forever.. ;) haha..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`photoCell` is not registered.. is this the actual code you have? because you have a white space `forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` remove the white space..

Happy coding, Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

Notice the code :

```
[_photoPicker registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"photoUploadCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@" photoUploadCell"];
```

Remove the white space from `@" photoUploadCell"`

Hope this will fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

You registered it with a different name`photoUploadCell`, than the one you use later on `photoCell`.

Comment: Sorry I' didn't payed attention I forgot to change variable name, (I was making some test) any way this is not resolving my problem

Answer (score 0):

1 : First modified your code with this

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        photoUploadCollectionViewCell *cell= (photoUploadCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoUploadCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    }
```

2 : in this code

```
 [_photoPicker registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"photoUploadCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:**@" photoUploadCell"]**;
```

in  `@" photoUploadCell"` there is space with Identifier make sure space are remove and match with nib and cell and register with same Identifier.
cheers